# POST variable while using Ajax

Tags: php, ajax

I'm using POST form with ajax, but i just can't use the POST variables and i couldn't figure out why.
I did try Ajax type/method
What else should i try?

index.html

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('form').on('submit', function (e) {
          e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type:'post',
        url: 'update-user.php',
        data: $('form').serialize(),
        dataType: "text",
          success: function (str) {
              $('#message').text(str)
            }
        })
    });
});
</script>
<p id="message"> </p>
    <form action="/" id="useredit">
<input type="hidden" id="id" value="1">
  <input type="text" id="firstname" value="test">
  <input type="submit" name="update" value="updateuser">
</form>
```

update-user.php

```
<?php 
     if (isset($_POST['update'])) {
          echo "sucsses"; 
     }
     else
     {
          echo "faild";
     }

    ?>
```

Comment: [Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Have you included the jQuery library in the project? Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server?](http://jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html)

Comment: Note: Only "successful controls" are serialized to the string. No submit button value is serialized since the form was not submitted using a button ([reference](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/))

Comment: Of Course I'm using jQuery library, there are no error, i know the ajax work because i do get the "failed" message.  I also tried button but still failed.

Comment: You haven't read the comment about "successful controls" or you just didn't understand it: You pass the form via ajax so you DON'T send the button value to the server (`if (isset($_POST['update'])) {`)!

Comment: I did read it, and tried it with text input it's also dont work. And as i read the ajax post should send me those value's, so i can't figure out what is my problem

Answer (score 0):

Try this 
You need to include datatype here

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('form').on('submit', function (e) {
          e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type:'post',
        url: 'update-user.php',
        data: $('form#useredit').serialize(),
          success: function (str) {
              $('#message').text(str)
            }
        })
    });
});
```

Comment: I think you're wrong, please read my comment on the question itself

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#submit').click(function (e) {
          e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url: 'update-user.php',
        data : $("#form").serialize(),
        dataType: "text",
          success: function (str) {
              $('#message').text(str)
            }
        })
    });
});
```